# How do I get a Debian server to output "screen -ls" on ssh login?

Tags: ssh, scripting, login

I read that I can add a line like this to /etc/ssh/sshd_config: `ForceCommand /etc/ssh/loginscript.sh`

The "loginscript.sh" is executable and only does `screen -ls` until now. I suppose the problem is, that it is executed in another shell instance, right? I didn't get any output on login yet.

EDIT:
OK, I solved the initial problem: Normal users had no permissions to execute the script in `/etc`. I moved it to `/`, now it works and echos to the login shell.

Next problem: The SSH connection closes directly after the script is executed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to severely restrict what your users can do, `ForceCommand` is not the way to go about doing this. Instead, add `screen -ls` to the bottom of the system-wide `.bashrc` (or equivalent, depending on what shell you're using).

For the bash shell on debian-based systems, you can find this at `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Now I stumbled across the Problem, that the script is also being executed when I start screen. Do you have any other idea on how to display running screen sessions on SSH login?

Maybe have a script running repeatedly, that puts the info in the `/etc/motd` ?